# signing an NSString using a private key generated with OpenSSL

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, encryption, rsa

I'm trying to use RSA to sign a token within a HTTP header that I have to pass to a web service - the requirements are that I should encrypt using my own private key and give them my public key. This is used purely so verify that the message was sent by me.

I'm aware of *many* similar questions on SO but I've been through *many* attempts so far this morning and am still no closer to something I assumed would be trivial.

I can find many examples of using RSA and encrypting using a public key, but my requirement is for me to sign with the private key.

It looks (from initial attempts) that the apple sample security code and most other examples that borrow from it always generate a private/public keypair using keychain - I would prefer to generate my keys using OpenSSL so I can distribute the public key to my client.

I've managed to generate some keys and it looks like I can load the private key using this code (apologies, I can't recall the source as I've been mixing implementations for hours):

```
-(SecKeyRef) getPrivateKeyRef {
    NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rsaPrivate" ofType:@"p12"];
    NSData *p12Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:resourcePath];

    NSMutableDictionary * options = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    SecKeyRef privateKeyRef = NULL;

    //change to the actual password you used here
    [options setObject:@"xxxx" forKey:(__bridge id)kSecImportExportPassphrase];

    CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);

    OSStatus securityError = SecPKCS12Import((__bridge CFDataRef) p12Data,
                                         (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)options, &items);

    if (securityError == noErr && CFArrayGetCount(items) > 0) {
        CFDictionaryRef identityDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
        SecIdentityRef identityApp = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict,
                                         kSecImportItemIdentity);

        securityError = SecIdentityCopyPrivateKey(identityApp, &privateKeyRef);
        if (securityError != noErr) {
            privateKeyRef = NULL;
        }
    }

    CFRelease(items);
    return privateKeyRef;
}
```

which seems to return me a valid `SecKeyRef` but I don't know how to use this to sign an `NSString`.

There seems to be so many ways to tackle this question (build OpenSSL and link to it, use Apple's keychain methods, use a partially complete library on GitHub) but I keep reaching a dead end - it would be ideal to get a proper, complete solution to this one.

Something along the lines of:

```
NSString* signedString = [rsaHelper signString: @"Hello, World!" WithPrivateKey:@"rsaPrivate.p12"];
```

And given a string encrypted with the public key:

```
NSString* decryptedString = [rsaHelper decryptString: @"DK5tkgkfjkJJft=" WithPrivateKey:@"rsaPrivate.p12"];
```

would be valuable! Please note, I'm not afraid of writing this code myself in any way, but would appreciate a nudge in the right direction :-)

Comment: Signing with a private and public key are the same operation, just done with different keys.   The idea behind asymmetric key encryption is that the two keys work as a pair, in either direction.   When information is being sent to you, it's encrypted with your public key and can only be decrypted with your private key.   When information is sent from you, it's encrypted with your private key and can only be decrypted with your public key.  For signatures, the same rules apply.  Since you state you've got code that can encrypt with the public key, you should be able to just change keys.

Comment: Unfortunately I get an OSStatus error if I provide the private key to the function 
        OSStatus status = SecKeyEncrypt(key, kSecPaddingPKCS1,(const uint8_t *)[buffer bytes],[buffer length],cipherBuffer,&cipherBufferSize);

This doesn't happen it I provide a public key

Comment: What error are you getting?